# jQuery div doesn't animate properly

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

the code first.

*HTML*

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Fabian">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap2">
  <div class="phone">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/phonewhite.png"  alt="Fabian "></a>
  </div>
  <div class="xdiv">
    <img src="images/x.png" alt="Fabian">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap3"></div>
<div class="wrap4"></div>
<div class="wrap5"></div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(".wrap2").click(function(){
    $(".wrap2").css("height","400px");
    $(".wrap3").animate({top:'570px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap4").animate({top:'740px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap5").animate({top:'910px'}, 500); 
    $(".xdiv").css("visibility","visible");                 
});
$(".xdiv").click(function(){                  
    $(".wrap2").animate({height:'170px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap3").animate({top:'340px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap4").animate({top:'510px'}, 10);
    $(".wrap5").animate({top:'680px'}, 10);
    $(".xdiv").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

The `xdiv` is inside the `wrap2` div. The problem is, that the other `wrap`s  (3,4,5) also animate accordingly if I click on the `wrap2` div, but not if I click on the "xdiv" to reset them. The animation starts, but rerolls immediately to the attributes from the `wrap2` click function. Here a jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/yxtQ5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this variant works also for me:

```
$(".xdiv").click(function(){                  
    $(".wrap2").animate({height:'170px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap3").animate({top:'340px'}, 500);
    $(".wrap4").animate({top:'510px'}, 10);
    $(".wrap5").animate({top:'680px'}, 10);
    $(".xdiv").css("visibility","hidden");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your xdiv is wrapped in wrap2. So when you click xdiv its parent  is notified of the click event.

Either pull the xdiv out of wrap2 or use  [**`stopPropagation()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
 $(".xdiv").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //stops parent handler from being notified of the event.
    //code here 

 });
```

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yxtQ5/4/